# How to turn up light bounces to infinity

Tags: mirror

I'm trying to make an [infinity mirror](https://www.google.com/search?q=infinity%20mirror&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwimg5r0sbzXAhVDx1QKHRxYBycQ_AUICygC&biw=1509&bih=804#imgrc=OOItacYWZKa2OM:) in blender. I've managed to make a two way mirror by using the back facing geometry input to apply two different materials to either side of a face. Everything works OK but I only get 6 layers of bounce between the two mirrored layers before it stops.

How can I turn the number of bounces up to infinity so that the light pattern continues on indefinitely or until it fades to black?

Thanks. Here is an example rendering:

[image: Limited bounces]

Comment: Try a really high number of bounces, like 100,000?

Comment: Would you add the result of the answer? Would be nice to see the effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Increase **Transparency Bounces** and **Glossy Bounces** in the Light paths

[image]

More info: [Simulate Infinity mirror effect](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47305/simulate-infinity-mirror-effect)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final result (to fill the request above)

[image]