# How can I make a 3D object that looks transparent on the outside and mapped on the inside?

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, transparency

Id been trying to make the same structure that this artist did for his model I don't know how to even call it, well heres the example from deu3884 on sketchfav whom I'm not trying to copy but instead understand in what way he did this and how can it be done on Blender.

[image]

[image]

I just want to know how to do the clouds and all the surroundings and if its possible to make it on cycles render. Thank you for the attention.

Comment: use the geometry backfacing node to control the transparency. someting like this:https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40782/backface-culling-as-a-mesh-property/40785#40785 and  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36388/how-to-setup-shaders-for-semitransparent-mirrors/36390#36390